# Java deepToString() method not working on array of primitives

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayDemo1 {
  public static void main (String args[]) {

    //reversing array and inspecting it using Arrays.deepToString()

    int[] array1 = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    int[] reversed_array = ArrayDemo1.reverse(array1);
    for (int i=0; i < reversed_array.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println(reversed_array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reversed_array));
  }

  public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
    int[] result = new int[list.length];

    for (int i = 0, j = result.length - 1; i < list.length; i++, j--) {
      result[j] = list[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Error:

> incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to Object[]

It looks like in this post:
[What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

they use Arrays.deepToString to print out arrays of primitives right?

This is the code in that referenced post:

```
*// array of primitives:*
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
*// for when you have other elements (other than strings) use the code below*
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(*your arrays name*));
*//output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*
```

Comment: Which specific answer are you talking about? For the most part, I'm seeing `deepToString` being used for arrays of arrays in that page...

Comment: if you change everything to Object[] where you have int[] it will work

Comment: You can just use `Arrays.toString()` instead of `Arrays.deepToString()`.  You have an array of `int`, not an array of arrays.

Comment: That answer has been incorrectly edited by someone also new to this subject and unfortunately edit was [approved (automatically)](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10076556) because one of reviewers instead of rejecting it decided to improve it by correcting only one of problems with it, but didn't noticed other problems. I rolled back answer to its previous state which contains proper examples.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @Pshemo

Answer (score 4):

The error is exactly what the compiler says.  You have an `int[]`, but you cannot pass it into a method that expects an `Object[]`, much like you can't pass an `int` (or any other primitive) where an `Object` is required.

Using a recursive string conversion method such as [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) is unnecessary here.  This method only takes an `Object[]`, because only an array of object references can refer to other arrays, making the recursion necessary.  An array of primitives can only hold primitive values -- there is no need to take each individual element and recursively call `deepToString` on it; they are primitive values already.  In fact, `Arrays.deepToString`'s javadocs state:

> If an element e is an array of a primitive type, it is converted to a string as by invoking the appropriate overloading of `Arrays.toString(e)`. If an element e is an array of a reference type, it is converted to a string as by invoking this method recursively.

The method `Arrays.deepToString` itself must notice if an internal element is a primitive array, and it calls `Arrays.toString` in that case.

Use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) instead, which has overloads for each primitive array type.